# Does commented html causes page loading time

Tags: html, performance, optimization

Does commented html elements and White spaces will causes page loading time.I know commented markup will not run by browser.compressing markup is the good idea while deploying in server

```
<!--Html Elements -->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It won't be run by the browser, but it will be in every case streamed by the server, and  downloaded by the client. It shouldn't make any difference, as long as you don't have enourmous amounts of characters in there.

If you're using dynamic pages generated server side, you might be interested in server-side comments, that don't get streamed in the response, so the client never downloads/sees them.For instance, in JSP, `<%-- this is a server-side comment --%>`.

Also, remember that javascript code is not affected by these comments, actually, `<!-- -->` is used to to avoid javascript code showing up on old old browsers that didn't support javascript. See this link: [Hiding JS code from old browsers](http://www.javascripter.net/faq/hidingjs.htm).

Comment: What about unwanted  white spaces.compressing markup while deploying is good idea

Comment: <kbd>Whitespace</kbd> is a character as well, and will also be increasing your page size. There are tools out there that can help you optimize your pages regarding this matter, but it won't make a difference if you don't have an awful lot of visits and an awful lot of whitespaces/comments in your pages.

Answer (score 2):

It will still increase your page size, but shouldn't be a problem. Having 10000 lines of commented-out HTML is going to be a problem though, but keeping your comments small, should not increase the page size by too much.

Answer (score 0):

Your page size will be increased but the execution time will stay the same as the comments are not parsed.

If you are using a server-side language, you can use their comments instead, like so:

```
<ul>
    <li>Something</li>
    <?php /* <li>Else</li> */ ?>
</ul>
```

This will hide the HTML from anyone poking around in your source code and will reduce the page size as the commented out HTML will not be sent to the user.

You could also use PHP's output control functions to automatically strip out any HTML comments. More info here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.outcontrol.php

You can also use those functions to compress your pages, remove whitespace, etc, which will also speed up page load by decreasing page size.